# How to access an element of a field in a structure directly

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have structure of arrays defined like in the following code sample:

```
struct Struct {
   float *field;
};
```

where field is an array of arbitrary length with index `idx`.
Currently i am filling these arrays as follows:

```
float *field_ptr = a->field;
field_ptr[idx] = 1.0f;
```

Is there a direct way to fill the array without the intermediate field_ptr pointer? I tried a couple of ways but unfortunately i am not exactly a C or pointer guru so I ran into out-of-bounds memory problems.

Edit 1: It may be useful to know that this is part of a (Py)Cuda code.
Edit 2: The code resides in a sample function with the following (pointer) declaration:

```
void testfunction(Struct *a)
{
    int idx = get_index();
    float *field_ptr = a->field;
    field_ptr[idx] = 1.0f;
}
```

Comment: Did you by any chance mean `a_field = a.field`?

Comment: @iharob actually i meant field_ptr in the second line instead of a_ptr, it was a typo. I didn't use a.field anywhere, see answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course there is; just use:

```
a->field[idx] = 1.0f;
```

if `a` is of type `Struct *`.

If the instance is a pointer to a struct, you need to dereference it using `->` operator, and if it's not a pointer it's the `.` operator.  Example:

```
struct Struct x;
/* you need to allocate space for the floats first */
x.field[0] = value;
```

and

```
struct Struct *x;
/* you need to allocate space for the floats first, and x must be a valid pointer */
x->field[0] = value;
```

Comment: This my first attempt but unfortunately i get errors: expression must have class type

Comment: @nlooije please post the exact error, copy and paste.

Comment: @nlooije are you using C++?

Comment: @RyanHaining: I am using Cuda which i guess technically is C++.

Comment: @iharob: the error message is exactly 'error: expression must have class type', that is the error which appears for everytime i use a.field

Comment: @nlooije c and c++ are not the same, are you aware of that? In co you can't do `Struct *a` with your current struct definition, you would need this instead `struct Struct *a`.

Comment: a yes now it make sense! i am ofcourse aware that they are not the same, but in this case its not the difference in C vs C++ but if it is a pointer to a struct or not. That i didnt realize how to do... thx